# How to reduct the case $\mathcal Quot_{Y/k}(\mathcal F ,P)$ to $\mathcal Quot_{P^{n}/k}(i_{*}\mathcal F ,P)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $k$.And let   $i$:  $X \rightarrow P^{n}$ be a closed embedding.Then for any coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ over $X$ and any polynomial $P \in Q[Z]$.I can  prove $\mathcal Quot_{P^{n}/k}(i_{*}\mathcal F ,P) $ is representable. And I want to show that $ \mathcal Quot_{Y/k}(\mathcal F ,P)$ is also representable by using the  natural transformation
$$ \mathcal Quot_{Y/k}(\mathcal F ,P) \rightarrow  \mathcal Quot_{P^{n}/k}(i_{*}\mathcal F ,P) $$ which is injective as $i^{*}i_{*}=id$
I think  $ \mathcal Quot_{Y/k}(\mathcal F ,P)$ is a closed subfunctor of  $\mathcal Quot_{P^{n}/k}(i_{*}\mathcal F ,P) $,  but i can't prove it.

Comment: Injective morphism of proper schemes is a closed immersion here is a source: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I feel sorry for not expressing my question clearly, I have re-edited it

Comment: $i_*$ induces an equivalence of categories between coherent sheaves on $X$ and coherent sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$ supported on $X$ so your natural transformation is manifestly an isomorphism.